# Firestore ignore limit (on flutter)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple collections, and to test, i have created 10k documents in this collections.
After that, when i do a simple query with limit(5):

```
Firestore.instance.collection(myCollection).orderBy(myOrderBy).limit(5).getDocuments();
```

And i see that in my console :

```
W/CursorWindow(21291): Window is full: requested allocation 253420 bytes, free space 68329 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
I/zygote64(21291): Background concurrent copying GC freed 535155(13MB) AllocSpace objects, 5(1240KB) LOS objects, 50% free, 17MB/35MB, paused 60us total 102.836ms
```

When i go to my Dashboard Firebase i see i have 10k read.

So I conclude that my query returns 6 results, but that it reads the entire database. Which can quickly decrease performance and increase the price.

I looked for a solution and I find this:

```
Firestore.instance.settings(persistenceEnabled: false;)
```

It seems to be working, but I have trouble understanding.
By default Firestore loads the entire collection to be able to make requests Offline?
Changing the firestore settings when launching the application would be enough, I'm not likely to be surprised?
And if I disable persistence I assume that if the user makes an offline write request, it will no longer be persisted when he is online again. Is a compromise possible?

Thanks,

Comment: Firestore's offline storage behaves as a cache, persisting any documents it has recently seen. Did you add the 10K documents from the same client where you are running the query by any chance? If so, the local cache of that client may/would contain all those documents, since the client added them. You'll want to uninstall/reinstall the client to wipe the cache in that case, to get a more realistic experience of what your users would get.

Comment: Oh thank you, I understand better! I have uninstall/reinstall, and it's true that I no longer have the memory problem logs.
But I still haven't understood something. If the data is in cache, this does not explain the 10K read request made to the server.

Comment: That's a separate issue as far as I'm concerned, and could be cause by many things, but definitely not by executing the query you have once for a single user. One things to keep in mind is that documents loaded in the console are also charged reads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore's offline storage behaves as a cache, persisting any documents it has recently seen. It does not pre-load documents you haven't told it to load with a query/read operation, so in the query you show that would be at most 5 documents for each time you execute the query.

Did you add the 10K documents from the same client where you are running the query by any chance? If so, the local cache of that client may/would contain all those documents, since the client added them. You'll want to uninstall/reinstall the client to wipe the cache in that case, to get a more realistic experience of what your users would get.

The fact that you see 10K reads in your usage tab is a separate issue, not explained by the code you shared. One things to keep in mind is that documents loaded in the console are also charged reads.

Comment: So my memory problem came from the cache too large after making my 10k insert query. I'm going to look for why I had 10k of reading, if it does not come from the firebase persistence it reassures me, I must undoubtedly have a little problem in my code. Thanks you so much Frank !